# MongoDB: two-sided unique key constraint

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

**Problem**: I'm creating a friend_requests collection in mongo, and i want to enforce a unique key between the two user id's (let's say for arguments sake i have a "from_user" and "to_user" key/column). However after testing, i've found that the uniqueness is only enforced in one direction.

**Current "Schema"**:

Here's my index:

```
> db.friend_requests.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "myapp.friend_requests",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "from_user" : 1,
            "to_user" : 1
        },
        "unique" : true,
        "ns" : "myapp.friend_requests",
        "name" : "from_user_1_to_user_1"
    }
]
```

Here's my data proving the uniqueness is one-way:

```
> db.friend_requests.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52cd715dcf75451e70450f6e"), "from_user" : "a", "to_user" : "b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52cd741cddf3114c4c501d19"), "from_user" : "b", "to_user" : "a" }
```

**Solution**

The preferred solution would not rely on management code to check uniqueness, however if im correct, there's not way to tell mongo to do this internally. So i guess the next best thing is management code that is as lightweight as possible.

One lightweight solution i found for mysql implementations is that you would always store the lowest key in the first column (i.e. "from_user" from my example, but i'd call it "user1" if i implemented this idea obviously), that way as long as you always insert new data in that format, the unique key constraint will always fire where required. The bonus of this implementation method being that when looking up existing requests between two users, you dont have to look for both varients (i.e. don't have to check if 1,2 or 2,1 as it should always just be 1,2 if the record exists).

Obviously that solution is based on the idea of mysql having an incrementing integer id. Mongo id's aren't integers, so i'm assuming there's not really a "smaller" id?

**Footnote**: I'm completely new to mongo, so i may just be making some seriously stupid db design mistake.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you can index a value, it must be [well-ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order), so you can compare any two indexable keys, even if they are of type `ObjectId`, `UUID`, etc, so the approach of always storing the lower value in a specific field works.

It is, however, important to make sure that comparison is implemented consistently. For instance, a comparison might convert to string and compare the strings. Alternateively, one might choose to compare the bytes directly, which would lead to different results on little-endian and big-endian machines.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you propose is sound. Create documents with the following schema and ensure that the application always places the lowest user ID in the `user1` field.

```
{
    user1: "a",
    user2: "b",
    ...
}
```

Then, create a [unique](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/) [compound](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) index on `{ user1 : 1, user2 : 1 }` to enforce the required uniqueness constraint.

Alternatively, if you would like to maintain the information about which user initiated the friend request, consider adding a third field to enforce uniqueness.  Create documents with the following schema:

```
{
    from_user : "a",
    to_user : "b",
    req_key : "ab",
    ...
}
```

The application can concatenate the two user IDs and store in the `req_key` field, ensuring that the lowest user ID comes first.  Then, add a unique index on `{ req_key : 1 }`.